# Python2: Writing to stdin of interactive process, using Popen.communicate(), without trailing newline

Tags: python, stdin

I am trying to write what I thought would be a simple utility script to call a different command, but Popen.communicate() seems to append a newline. I imagine this is to terminate input, and it works with a basic script that takes an input and prints it out, but it's causing problems when the other program is interactive (such as e.g.  `bc`).

Minimal code to reproduce, using bc in lieu of the other program (since both are interactive, getting it to work with bc should solve the problem):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = "bc"
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input="2+2")
print(stdout_data)
```

This prints `('', '(standard_in) 1: syntax error\n')`, presumably caused by the appended newline character, as piping the same string to bc in a shell, `echo "2+2" | bc`, prints `4` just fine.

Is it possible to use Popen.communicate() without appending the newline, or would I need to use a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm an idiot, because the solution was the opposite of what I thought: adding a newline to the input: `stdout_data = p.communicate(input="2+2\n")` makes the script print `('4\n', '')` as it should, rather than give an error.